# Have cargo print the name of the final generated executable, maybe through modifying build.rs?

Tags: rust-cargo, cargo

I run `cargo b` and `cargo r` from different environments (including command line and emacs in server or stand-alone configuration). An issue I regularly experience is that I then would like to run the generated program "manually", for example to test command-line options in a different context. However, sometimes the executable was not where I expected it (because, for example, emacs when started as daemon "saw" a different "CARGO_TARGET_DIR"). Also, for embedded projects I sometimes have profiles other that debug and release.

I understand I can run `cargo metadata` and extract some of the info from there, but this fails if cargo is started from an IDE such as emacs/rustic-mode. Of course I can start to hack the emacs config, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Is it possible to use `build.rs` to have cargo display the full path of the executable produced, ideally **at the end** of the build process? How can I achieve that